# Looking for a good resource on multithreading in C# and asp.net

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency

I need to learn in depths of multi-threading and concurrency using c#.Also how asp.net uses inbuilt multi-threading for performance and how can we fiddle with it for performance.

A good book or articles or videos is what i am looking for, subject being multithreading and concurrency.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562)

Comment: @AakashM, OK!! so where should i post such questions, some other stackexchange site maybe or nowhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link for slides http://www.cs.vu.nl/~tcs/cm/ that i referred to while studying multi-threading concepts. You can search for some examples in asp.net but have a look at this for learning the basics of multi threading and concurrency